# How to split two or more sentences connected using conjunctions like(and,or..etc) into two separate sentences?

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

I am new to stanford.I tried to split two or more independent sentences which are connected with conjunctions like (and,or..etc) into separate single sentences using stanford tree parser.

Example sentence - Lion and tiger are chasing a deer and fox is chasing a rabbit. I want split this for two independent sentences shown below.

1) Lion and tiger are chasing a deer.

2) fox is chasing a rabbit.

sentences should only have to break with conjunctions which connected **independent sentences**. **Not** for **two subjects**(Lion and tiger) or **two objects** connected with "and". If anyone knows please help me.

Parser tree structure

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Lion)
      (CC and)
      (NNP tiger))
    (VP (VBP are)
      (VP (VBG chasing)
        (SBAR
          (S
            (NP (DT a) (NNS deer)
              (CC and)
              (NN fox))
            (VP (VBZ is)
              (VP (VBG chasing)
                (NP (DT a) (NN rabbit))))))))))
```

Thanks.

Comment: From what you've posted, the phrase doesn't appear to have been parsed correctly, it looks like the software understood it as "Lion and tiger are chasing a deer and fox (which) is chasing a rabbit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parse looks incorrect — did this come from the Stanford Parser? When I input the same sentence on the [parser demo page](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp), I get the following:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP (NNP Lion)
        (CC and)
        (NNP tiger))
      (VP (VBP are)
        (VP (VBG chasing)
          (NP (DT a) (NNS deer)))))
    (CC and)
    (S
      (NP (NN fox))
      (VP (VBZ is)
        (VP (VBG chasing)
          (NP (DT a) (NN rabbit)))))
    (. .)))
```

With this parse, extracting the two independent clauses would be fairly easy. You can use [Tregex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html) (also part of CoreNLP) to search for sibling clauses (`S` constituents) with intervening conjunctions (`CC` nodes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To break sentence by using "S" tag if it needs  to consider brackets? In  this tree structure  first sentence opened and end with brackets and other sentence is also opened and closed with brackets. I want to break sentence into two not including tags but considering tags.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you want to know how to extract the constituent words of the independent sentences (i.e., get rid of tags and constituents in the tree)? You want the "yield" of each subtree in this case.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I don't have clear idea how to use yield. The result I gain mention above. Now I want to get only words without tags.

Comment: How are you doing this tree splitting? If you are doing this within CoreNLP (Java), the yield-related methods on Tree should be sufficient (once you have them split). (Please add extensions / extra information to your original question rather than to my answer.)

Comment: Just to help somebody else who comes across this post, and gets the same parsed tree as the original poster: the problem could be due to missing the full stop "." at the end of the input when giving it to the parser. Without it, I got the same tree as in the question, and with it, I got the tree as in the above answer by Jon.